# Install flash player before executing windows setup and deployment

Tags: flash, 32bit-64bit, setup-deployment, prerequisites

I want to install a flash player, if not already on the target machine, before executing my .net windows application set up msi created. Any clue? (I do have Flash installer)

Comment: Okk.I am not a partner but Flash Player is prerequisite for my application to run. My product owner wants me to check if it is installed and install it automatically if not already. What can be the correct and legal procedure to tackle this apart from becoming a partner?

Comment: That's correct.On some Windows,app runs fine but on OSs like Win7, it errors out.My product owner want to minimize dependency over the net so cant give link to download.The link you gave seems applicable for Web/Flex apps.Mine is Windows desktop application. Mismatch? Also,I didn't get why Flash redistribution is not allowed if it is available for free on their website? Anyways, leave about flash but in case, say if I want to run some exe (which I have on my machine) before/ during/after my main product installation, is there any option available for it in .NET Set Up and Deployment project?